Display Sub Application UI in Main Application MasterLayout in Angular
My Angular application has Main Application and Sub Application.
Main application loads with Master layout having Menu  on left side shown below

URL when click on Menu options available in Main Application:

http://localhost:4200/#/masterlayout/overview
http://localhost:4200/#/masterlayout/equipment?refresh=1719135509415
http://localhost:4200/#/masterlayout/alarms?refresh=1719135526331
http://localhost:4200/#/masterlayout/import-data?refresh=1719135547765

When I click on Media Menu option it should load the UI of sub application in the same master layout. Currently on Media menu option button click it opens the Sub Application UI but loads in complete screen shown below

Url when called Sub Application on Menu Option Click:

http://localhost:4200/#/app1/one?refresh=1719135570163

Expectation is shown in below image

=== masterlayout-routing.module.ts ===
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MasterlayoutPageComponent } from './masterlayout.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MasterlayoutPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'overview',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../overview/overview.module').then(
            (m) => m.OverviewPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'tutorials',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../tutorials/tutorials.module').then(
            (m) => m.TutorialsPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'equipment',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../equipment/equipment.module').then(
            (m) => m.EquipmentPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'alarms',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../alarms/alarms.module').then((m) => m.AlarmsPageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'app1',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../../../../projects/app1/src/app/app.module').then((m) => m.App1SharedModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'single-alarm/:id',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../single-alarm-view/single-alarm-view.module').then(
            (m) => m.SingleAlarmViewPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'app-information',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../app-information/app-information.module').then(
            (m) => m.AppInformationModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'analytics',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../../analytics/analytics.module').then(
            (m) => m.AnalyticsPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'import-data',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../../pages/import-data/import-data.module').then(
            (m) => m.ImportDataPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'work-order',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../../pages/work-order/work-order.module').then(
            (m) => m.WorkOrderPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'alarm-suppress',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../../pages/alarm-suppress/alarm-suppress.module').then(
            (m) => m.AlarmSuppressModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'remove-suppression',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../../pages/remove-suppression/remove-suppression.module').then(
            (m) => m.RemoveSuppressionModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'privacy-policy',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../privacy-policy/privacy-policy.module').then(
            (m) => m.PrivacyPolicyModule
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MasterlayoutPageRoutingModule {}

=== List of Pages with URL loading on MasterLayout ===
 this.listOfPages = [
      {
        title: 'OVERVIEW',
        icon: 'assets/icon/Icon-home_inactive.png',
        activeIcon: 'assets/icon/Icon-home_active.svg',
        url: '/masterlayout/overview',
        count: 0,
        showMenu: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'EQUIPMENT',
        icon: 'assets/icon/Icon-equipment_inactive.png',
        activeIcon: 'assets/icon/Icon-equipment_active-web.svg',
        url: '/masterlayout/equipment',
        count: 0,
        showMenu: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'ALARMS',
        icon: 'assets/icon/Icon-alarms_inactive.png',
        activeIcon: 'assets/icon/Icon-alarms_active.svg',
        url: '/masterlayout/alarms',
        count: 0,
        showMenu: true,
      },

      {
        title: 'MEDIA',
        icon: 'assets/icon/mobile_icon-manuals_inactive.svg',
        activeIcon: 'assets/icon/web_icon-manuals_active.svg',
        url: '/app1',
        count: 0,
        showMenu: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'IMPORT_DATA',
        icon: 'assets/icon/file_inactive.png',
        activeIcon: 'assets/icon/file_active.png',
        url: '/masterlayout/import-data',
        count: 0,
        showMenu: false,
      },
    ];

For the routing I have imported Module of Sub Application in Main application.
Please help me to understand if I need to change the routing so that I can load Sub App UI in Master Layout of Main Application.
